# how to solve this error.when i am running my project in then found gradle error

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, android-fragments

ERROR: Could not determine artifacts for androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0: No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: It seems like you dont have internet connection

Comment: Please go in setting and disable Offline Mode